# PyQt - Location of the window

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pyqt, pyqt5

```
def location_on_the_screen(self):
    fg = self.frameGeometry()
    sbrp = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().bottomRight()
    fg.moveBottomRight(sbrp)
    self.move(fg.topLeft())
```

I can't place the window in the bottom right corner of the screen. frameGeometry() not working as it should. Help me, please, what can I do?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Here's a possible solution for windows:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)

    def location_on_the_screen(self):
        ag = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry()
        sg = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()

        widget = self.geometry()
        x = ag.width() - widget.width()
        y = 2 * ag.height() - sg.height() - widget.height()
        self.move(x, y)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.location_on_the_screen()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 2):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QGridLayout, QWidget, QDesktopWidget
#------------------------------   
def center_window():
   qtRectangle = self.frameGeometry()
   centerPoint = QDesktopWidget().availableGeometry().center()
   qtRectangle.moveCenter(centerPoint)
   self.move(qtRectangle.topLeft())
   #---------------------------------
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.window_center():
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your 'window' is a subclass of `QWidget`. If so, the following should fit your needs:

```
import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QDesktopWidget


class MyWidget(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setFixedSize(400, 300)

    def location_on_the_screen(self):    
        screen = QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()
        widget = self.geometry()
        x = screen.width() - widget.width()
        y = screen.height() - widget.height()
        self.move(x, y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    widget = MyWidget()
    widget.location_on_the_screen()
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this code also not working as I need. :(
http://i.imgur.com/YY0Y67D.png

Comment: Works perfectly on macOS and Ubuntu. I have no Windows OS installed so I cannot test but it seems the problem to be the height of the start menu bar which is not being considered by `QDesktopWidget().screenGeometry()`.